# Is my inner tube causing sidewall rub

Tags: innertube

I’ve been running corsa vittoria for two years I recently changed my wheels to 38 mm depth with a width less than 25 mm as my bike takes a max of 25 mm width I’ve never had a tyre rub before using these tyre I’ve had the wheels checked and they run true do u think it’s the inner tubes or the tyre a rogue one ?

Regards D

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  What wheels did you have and what did you change to?  The inner tube shouldn't be able to affect the size of the casing unless the latter is about to fail.  Does it rub evenly around, or is there a specific spot where it rubs?

Comment: The same tyres will come up wider on wider rims   - that could easily be the problem, but we'd need quite a bit more detail to be sure

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing ever to do with the inner tube. The tire holds the shape and contains the pressure. The inner tube holds the air in so the tire stays inflated and is entirely supported by the tire.  Try to pump an inner tube to your normal tire inflation pressure and let us know how it goes (hint - a couple of PSI and the tube is twice the size of the tire, imagine if you got to tire pressures).

With new rims causing a new problem my first suspicion is the change of rims is the cause of the new problem. The new wheels may not be dished correctly and the rim is sitting off to one side. This is pretty obvious - the wheel is true but the gap between tire and chain stay on one side is more than the other.

It is possible that you damaged the tire removing it from the old rim and installing it on the new rim. Look for a bulge in the tire. If there is no obvious bulge, its simply the new rim and tire combination are too thick (it is incredibly unlikely the tire is 'bulged' around its entire circumference). You will need to either change rims or change tires.